# AWS Redshift Parquet COPY has an incompatible Parquet schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr, parquet

I am writing DataFrame to Redshift using temporary s3 bucket and Parquet as the temporary format. Spark successfully has written data to s3 temp bucket, but Redshift trying to COPY data to warehouse failed with the following error:

```
error:  S3 Query Exception (Fetch)
 code:      15001
 context:   Task failed due to an internal error. File 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/...../part-00001-de882e65-a5fa-4e52-95fd-7340f40dea82-c000.parquet  has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 's3://bucket-dev-e
 query:     17567
 location:  dory_util.cpp:872
 process:   query0_127_17567 [pid=13630]
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

**UPDATED 1**

This is the detailed error:

```
S3 Query Exception (Fetch). Task failed due to an internal error. 
File 'https://....d5e6c7a/part-00000-9ca1b72b-c5f5-4d8e-93ce-436cd9c3a7f1-c000.parquet  has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 's3://.....a-45f6-bd9c-d3d70d5e6c7a/manifest.json.patient_dob'. 
Column type: TIMESTAMP, Parquet schema:\noptional byte_array patient_dob [i:26 d:1 r:0]\n (s3://.......-45f6-bd9c-d3d70d5e6c7a/
```

Apache Spark version `2.3.1`

Also tried to set up the following properties with no luck:

```
writer
   .option("compression", "none")
   .option("spark.sql.parquet.int96TimestampConversion", "true")
   .option("spark.sql.parquet.int96AsTimestamp", "true")
   .option("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", "true")
```

Where may be the issue?

**UPDATED 2**

Dataframe `patient_dob` column type is `DateType`

Redshift `patient_dob` field type is `date`

S3 select shows the following on `patient_dob` Parquet field - `"patient_dob": "1960-05-28"`

Comment: how did you write it? which library / compression. can you run sw select on it?

Comment: I write it by сustomized `spark-redshift` lib with parquet support. `spark.write.option("compression", "none")` BTW, what do you mean under `sw select` ?

Comment: sorry i misstyped - s3 select. go into s3 in aws console and then run select (by right clicking) on one of your files. I guess your spark redshift isnt working right - try just using pandas fastparquet if you can - see if that works - at least it would prove the cause?

Comment: `s3 select` returns data fine. Unfortunately, I'm unable to use pandas `fastparquet` because the application is written in Scala language

Comment: can you try following what I put here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405353/using-redshift-spectrum-to-read-the-data-in-external-table-in-aws-redshift - not exactly the same issue but it might help.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. Redshift fails on TIMESTAMP. If I remove this field everything is working fine.

Comment: what does that parquet timestamp look like (exactly) when you run s3 select

Comment: I also added Updated 2 section to my question with more details regarding data types

Comment: @JonScott Sorry for late answer. S3 select shows the following "patient_dob": "1960-05-28"

Comment: @alexanoid May I ask how you got the detailed error, I am facing similar issues.

Comment: Also getting this, my timestamp has microsecond precision and redshift really doesn't like it